# WCF service:400 bad request when accessing from local machine

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service hosted and the client is hosted on the same server. I try to show some error message via a dialog box. its working as expected when i try to perform some action which throws that error in server but its showing Bad request when i try to work on Local machine.

Can't post the configuration file. Client machine So :) . Hosting is IIS

I found that in the controllers catch block where i am calling the wcf service whenever we are having an exception we are setting

```
Respose.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return Json(execption.Message);
```

Does this have anything to do ?

I added this setting in the web config and i am able to see the actual message in my local machine too

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

Is there any other way of doing it from coding part

Comment: Thanks for the update mentioning it is IIS however it's still hard to know whats going on with the little info you have posted

Comment: does IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults is true in web config. default is false and error detail will send to clients in local machine only.[IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649234.aspx)

Comment: Yes it is set to true.